# Sort results by sort_order with Doctrine phpcr-odm

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm, doctrine-phpcr

Using a Document class with [PHPCR-ODM](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/book/database_layer.html), it is possible to [fetch results with the class repository](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/book/database_layer.html#fetching-objects-from-phpcr), the results are automatically sorted by a field `sort_order` that is not in the Document class but in the database schema.

Example of a query logged in the Symfony Profiler:

`SELECT path FROM phpcr_nodes WHERE parent = ? AND workspace_name = ? ORDER BY sort_order ASC`

I have this simply query built with queryBuilder :

```
$qb->from()
        ->document('AppBundle\Document\Product', 'product')
        ->end()
        ->where()
        ->neq()->field('product.type')->literal('category');
$query = $qb->getQuery();
```

The result is not sorted by the field `sort_order` like other queries, and I can't use the `orderBy` method as this is not a field of the Document class.

So, how can I sort my results?

Comment: Still confusing, read again "the results are automatically sorted by a field `sort_order` that is not in the Document class" then later "The result is not sorted by the field `sort_order` like other queries", do you want your query to sort by such `sort_order` column? In the other side I don't know how the rest of the queries are sorting "automatically" by `sort_order` because AFAIK that's not possible maybe I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Who said you can't use `orderBy()`? You should [read the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-phpcr-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#ordering-results) because certainly it's possible. Using your same code and assuming the sort column as `sort_order` see below:

```
$qb->from()
   ->document('AppBundle\Document\Product', 'product')
   ->end()
   ->where()
   ->neq()->field('product.type')->literal('category')
   ->orderBy()->desc()->field('product.sort_order');
```

Comment: I can use `orderBy()`, but not with this field because it's not within my Document class.

Comment: Then how do you expect to sort by something which is not in your document? That does not make any sense to me!!! Is `sort_order` is coming from any other Document then just use `JOIN` in your QB to reach such column wherever it's and apply the same concept as shown on my answer

Comment: When you use the `find()` method on the DocumentRepository class, hte results are sorted by this field. For example : `SELECT path FROM phpcr_nodes WHERE parent = ? AND workspace_name = ? ORDER BY sort_order ASC`

Comment: I am confused now, sorry but I am not following you, can you re-elaborate your question?

Comment: I have updated my initial post, hope it is more clear now. Thank you.